# Exporting MODIS AOD monthly(mean) composite for 5 years

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, modis, image, composite

I am writing a code in Google Earth Engine, in which I want to export the image composite of mean monthly MODIS AOD for 5 years.
I am writing the following code, but whenever I try to run it the webpage got hang and says Aw Snap.

```
var createaodcomposite = function () {
  var yearstart = 2005;
  var yearend = 2009;
  var listaod = ee.Image([]);
  for (var loopYear = yearstart; loopYear <= yearend; loopYear = +1) {
    var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(loopYear, 6, 01);
    var end = ee.Date.fromYMD(loopYear, 12, 25);

    var aod = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES")
      .select('Optical_Depth_047')
      .filterBounds(geometry)
      .filterDate(start, end)
    var finalop = aod.reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).clip(study).rename(loopYear.toString());
    var filename = ("Optical_Depth_047_").concat(loopYear.toString());

    listaod = listaod.addBands(finalop.rename(filename));
  }
  print(listaod, 'List AOD')
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: listfin,
    description: 'yearly_AOD_ts',
    //Image resolution is 1000m
    scale: 1000,
    region: study,
    crs: 'epsg:4326',
  })
}
var comp = createaodcomposite();
print(comp)
```

Comment: For loop won't work with server-side functions. Use map instead. Check https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server. Here on this site there are several examples of how to use map

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you're good with client-side loop. That is, if you hadn't turned it into an infinite loop.

```
for (var loopYear = yearstart; loopYear <= yearend; loopYear = +1)
```

You want this to be:

```
for (var loopYear = yearstart; loopYear <= yearend; loopYear += 1)
```